# print first and last name with def keyword in python

Tags: python-3.x

Hi I am self learning python to make advantage of current lockdown sitution.I want to print first and last name. I have used the def keyword to do so. I am not able to get the reesult.
Could you please help me out?

```
def student(firstname, lastname):
    fullname = 'Sameer Shrestha'
    return fullname
    print(student)

def student(firstname, lastname):
    fullname = 'Sameer Shrestha'
    print(fullname)

def student(firstname, lastname):
    fullname = 'Sameer Shrestha'
    print(student)

def name(firstname,lastname):
    return name
    fullname = name(Sameer,Shrestha)
    print(name)
```

I have used four different ways.But all of them gives does not give result. It gives blank screen.
Could you please help me out?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're attempting.  What is it you're wanting the `student` function to do?

Comment: @DanielWalker I want to print first and last name. As you can see full name has value as Sameer Shrestha. I want to print it. But using the def keyword initially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function needs to use the input parameters, `firstname` and `lastname`, that it was given.  It shouldn't always return "Sameer Shrestha".  For example, you want to be able to handle

```
full_name = name('Daniel','Walker')
print(full_name)
```

and have it print

```
Daniel Walker
```

So, what is a full name?  It is a composed of `firstname` and `lastname` with a space between them.  You can form this using string concatenation.  For example,

```
x='foo'
y='bar'
z=x+y
print(z)
```

will print

```
foobar
```

Your function needs to return the full name.  So,

```
def name(first_name, last_name):
    return first_name + ' ' + last_name

full_name = name('Sameer','Shrestha')
print(full_name)
```

Comment: @Danilel Walker thank you for clarifying me with the code. It was really helpful. It is working fine now.

Comment: Glad to hear it!  Keep on coding!

Comment: Sure will do. But I am very new to programming. So I may have to juggle here and there and might keep on posting questions in stack overflow if I have any confusion. I hope I would get some help from it.

Comment: This is a channel I've found very helpful: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCCezIgC97PvUuR4_gbFUs5g

Comment: Thank you Daniel. I will certain follow it.